# How to maintain the calories in rice (which were present in it in its raw form) after cooking it?

Tags: rice, calories

I searched Google with the following keywords:

> calories in 1 tbsp brown rice

The result was:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the calories, after cooking have severely reduced.

**What can I do to maintain the default level of calories in cooked rice?**

I am not talking about increasing calories by adding extra materials like oil. I wish to know some cooking method which does not destroy the calories so much.

***Note: I do NOT throw any water during the process of cooking rice.***

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm afraid you interpret the tables wrong. You aren't destroying calories, you are adding water (=0 cal) to the dry rice. As the rice absorbs the water, you are in fact measuring rice + water for cooked rice.

This is true for calorie tables that measure by volume (like here) and by weight.

---

If you are cooking your rice by boiling and straining, you are effectively losing a few calories due to the starch that gets drained with the water, but that's not what you asked here.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is water. 1 TBS uncooked rice has 3 times the volume after it's cooked. No calories are lost.