# How many calories are in a cup of rice?

Tags: rice, calories

Typical googling tells me a cup of white rice has ~200 calories, but the bags of white rice I purchase tell me a quarter cup of dry rice has 150 calories (Jasmine, in this case, but others have been about the same), which would mean a cup would have 600 calories.

Which is it? And what's the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/65969/how-to-maintain-the-calories-in-rice-which-were-present-in-it-in-its-raw-form

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I’m afraid you may have misunderstood some results (or they were unclear in their descriptions).

A ballpark number for rice volume is that cooking white rice will give you about triple the dry rice volume.

So let’s look at your data:
1/4 cup of *raw* rice makes 3/4 cups of *cooked* rice. The calories don’t change, assuming that you add just water and don’t pour away a significant amount of starch. So you still have 150 kcal for 1/4 cup of dry or 3/4 cups of cooked rice.

If 3/4 cup cooked white rice has 150 kcal, one cup of cooked white rice is roughly 200 kcals - which is exactly what you found out.

Answer (score -3):

That depends on whether you're talking about cooked or uncooked rice. 1 cup will cook to 3 cups. 3/4 cup will cook to 1 cup. 1 cup uncooked rice will be around 600 calories. 1 cup cooked rice will be around 300 calories.

Comment: 1 cup becomes 3 cups cooked, but 3/4 cup becomes 1 cup cooked? Something doesn't add up (or multiply out, as it were) here...